# Recursion with Logarithmic Time complexity

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

This is a homework problem. Not expecting the solution.. Just looking for a nudge in the right direction!

Design a fast algorithm with logarithmic time complexity to compute the triple (N(n),N(n−1),N(n−2)). Write a recursive function that on an input n>3, returns the above triple. For sufficiently large n, the routine should use considerably fewer operations in total than the obvious method of computing N(n).

Given:

```
N(0) = 0
N(1) = N(2) = N(3) = 1
N(n) = N(n-1) + N(n-3)
N(2k) = N(k)N(k) + 2N(k)N(k−2) + N(k−1)N(k−1) and
N(2k−1) = N(k)N(k) + 2N(k−1)N(k−2)
```

** The obvious method is computing values in the sequence N(0), N(1).. N(n) and hence being able to use the pre-computed values. This takes O(n).

Comment: My first instinct would be to see if [memoizing it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) is enough.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify. As stated, I jumped at Memoization too. But, it is immediately obvious that it can never be less than linear in expense(of time).

Comment: Memoization wouldn't compute all the values up to n, though. It'd compute substantially fewer than that, and my first instinct would be to check if the number of values needed would be logarithmic in n.

Comment: I've spoken to a few classmates. I hear Memoization is not what is expected. There is a matrix exponentiation method for Fibonacci numbers. Surely, it can be used in this case? If yes, any pointers?

Comment: Memoization might not be what's expected, but it works. I've listed another way to approach the problem that performs the same computations without memoization. I don't see any straightforward way to apply matrix exponentiation to this, since you aren't dealing with linear combinations of previous values.

Answer (score 0):

Just memoize it. The recursive calls all land in a number of logarithmically spaced clusters, and you can prove a simple bound on the maximum size of these clusters. As this is homework, I leave the proof up to you.

(Alternatively, you can write a function that computes the values for an entire cluster with one recursive call to get the values for the next lower cluster. This is likely the approach they had in mind.)